# what is reason how it working as implicit conversion by JS

Tags: javascript

```
true == "Hello"  // False
```

true is a truthy value and also `Hello` is also a truthy value why it outputting in false

how implicit conversion takes place in this

Comment: `boolean != string`, try `true == !!'Hello'`

Comment: `==` does not compare the truthiness of two values, it performs a lot of different typecasts (in this case, both values get casted to a number, `true` -> 1, `"Hello"` -> NaN), and then compares the values (1 == NaN -> false)

Comment: @JonasWilms "true" == true evaluates false!

Comment: @seeSharper uh, yes, `==` performs so many typecasts in different directions that I've messed them up, edited my comment ...

Comment: Clearly nothing wrong with this question given the difficulty I and others had answering it fully correctly. Do wish people would be a bit less trigger happy with the downvotes.

Comment: @seesharper agreed and it's frustrating that downvotes are not included with an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of asking the question "is the boolean literal `true` the same thing as the string `"Hello"`" is `false` because, well, those two *are* different things.

By your argument, because `"Hello"` is a truthy value, and `"World"` is a truthy value, `"Hello" == "World"` should be `true`, but that would mean that string comparison would be completely useless.

> how implicit conversion takes place in this

As per [clause 7.2.15 *Abstract Equality Comparison*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), subclause 8, `true` gets implicitly converted to `1`. This then gets us to subclause 4, in which `"Hello"` gets implicitly converted to `NaN`, which then brings us to subclause 1, which will evaluate [`1 === NaN`, which is `false`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison).